# How can I remove the duplicate rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

In my `df`, I define `c('apple', 'banana')` and `c('banana', 'apple')` are the same, casue the fruit type is the same just the arrangement is different.

Then, How can I remove row No.1 and row No.2 and only keep the last row(`wanted_df`).

```
df = data.frame(fruit1 = c('apple', 'banana', 'fig'),
                fruit2 = c('banana', 'apple', 'cherry'))
df

wanted_df = df[3,]
```

Any help will be high appreciated!

============================

Something wrong with my real data.

The `frames2` loses rows which `lag = 2`.
I wanted data frame shold like `wanted_frames`.

```
pollution1 = c('pm2.5', 'pm10', 'so2', 'no2', 'o3', 'co')
pollution2 = c('pm2.5', 'pm10', 'so2', 'no2', 'o3', 'co') 
dis = 'n'
lag = 1:2

frames = expand.grid(pollution1 = pollution1, 
                     pollution2 = pollution2,
                     dis = dis, 
                     lag = lag) %>% 
  mutate(pollution1 = as.character(pollution1),
         pollution2 = as.character(pollution2), 
         dis = as.character(dis)) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(pollution1 != pollution2)

vec<- with(frames, paste(pmin(pollution1, pollution2), pmax(pollution1, pollution2)))

frames2 = frames[!duplicated(vec), ]

wanted_frames = frames2 %>% mutate(lag = 2) %>% bind_rows(frames2)
```

Comment: Could you show an expected output? How what you like `frames2` to appear, if you just showed a manual example.

Comment: @ cmirian, Hi, the last code `wanted_frames` is my expected output.

Comment: `pollution1` and `pollution2` are identical. So if you apply `filter` that omits duplicates, you gonna end up with zero rows. I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
library(dplyr)
d <- filter(df, !(fruit1 %in% fruit2) | !(fruit2 %in% fruit1))
```

Which gives

```
> d
  fruit1 fruit2
1    fig cherry
```

**Update**

As commented by @JonSpring and @Phil, the updated code should be

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% filter(!(fruit1 %in% fruit2) | !(fruit2 %in% fruit1))%>% ungroup()
```

Comment: Such a simple idea. Shouldn't it be `filter(df, !(fruit1 %in% fruit2) | !(fruit2 %in% fruit1))`?

Comment: Sure, thank you @Phil - updated accordingly. Have a great weekend.

Comment: I don't believe this works in all cases, e.g for `df = data.frame(fruit1 = c('apple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'fig'), fruit2 = c('banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'cherry'))`.  In that case row 2 is a unique combination, but is filtered out b/c one of the elements is found in the other column in another row.

Comment: @JonSpring is correct - should be fixed with `df %>% rowwise() %>% filter(...) %>% ungroup()` but it could make it slower.

Answer (score 2):

A base R way :

```
vec<- with(df, paste(pmin(fruit1, fruit2), pmax(fruit1, fruit2)))
df[!(duplicated(vec) | duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE)), ]

#   fruit1 fruit2
#3    fig cherry
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, Thanks for your reply，but something wrong when I use your method in my real data, and I update my question.

Comment: @zhiweili 1) You have not used complete code of my answer. 2) For your shared dataframe all the values are duplicates so everything is removed from the data.

Comment: Hi, @ Ronak Shah, I have a new quesiton post on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72023327/can-not-use-pivot-longer-in-r-with-multile-cell-value-in-r. I think may be you could help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a low-tech dplyr approach. Make a sorted key, then keep rows with unique keys.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(key = paste(pmin(fruit1, fruit2), pmax(fruit1, fruit2))) %>%
    add_count(key) %>%
    filter(n == 1)
```